# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth does not work properly with NSMutableAttributedString on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to reduce the text size in order to fit a specific area width. The text contains some different format settings (mainly text color) so I am using [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring)

Then I set [adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth) for fitting with the bounding rectangle.

```
testLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
testLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
let attributedGreen = NSAttributedString(string: "GREEN", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green])
let attributedYellow = NSAttributedString(string: "YELLOW", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow])
let textCombination = NSMutableAttributedString()
textCombination.append(attributedGreen)
textCombination.append(attributedYellow)
textCombination.append(attributedGreen)
textCombination.append(attributedYellow)
testLabel.attributedText = textCombination
```

[image]

The expected result is to have a full visible text and re-scaled to the right font size but it does not happen and the text is truncated.

Everything is working fine if I do not use the attributed string:

```
testLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
testLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true     
testLabel.text = "GREENYELLOWGREENYELLOW"
```

[image]

Is that the right way for doing it? How can I properly re-scale the font size?

Extra note:
I've just tested it on a device running iOS 13 (instead of iOS 14) and font re-scale with attributed string is working fine.

[image]

Could it be an iOS 14 bug? Any workarounds to suggest?

UPDATE 2020/10/26: I've just tested it using iOS 14.0.1 and the issue is still present.

Comment: Down voted? Really?!?!?! BTW it seems to be a iOS 14 bug  https://openradar.appspot.com/FB8699725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a iOS 14 bug [openradar.appspot.com/FB8699725](http://openradar.appspot.com/FB8699725)
So, for a proper fix, we have to wait the new iOS release, in the meantime I apply the following quick-and-dirty workaround:

```
testLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
testLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

let attributedGreen = NSAttributedString(string: "GREEN", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green])
let attributedYellow = NSAttributedString(string: "YELLOW", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow])
let attributedWorkaroud = NSAttributedString(string: ".", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)])
let textCombination = NSMutableAttributedString()
textCombination.append(attributedGreen)
textCombination.append(attributedYellow)
textCombination.append(attributedGreen)
textCombination.append(attributedYellow)
textCombination.append(attributedWorkaroud)
testLabel.attributedText = textCombination
```

I've added a transparent dot at the end of the string.
It produces a little misalignment but at least the word is readable.

UPDATE 2020/12/17
Fixed in iOS 14.2

Comment: not work if there are different font attributes

Comment: Which attributes are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply set the minimum scale factor of the label to 0.5 either from storyBoard/Interface Builder or programatically like this

```
Yourlabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

Comment: it is already set to 0.1 (I've updated my question adding extra info)